# Duplicate filename with _0001, but zero file size

Tags: symbolic-link, filenames, duplicate

I have, somehow, created many duplicates of some files, they end in `_0001.php` for example.

I might have done this while trying to crete symbolic links. The sym links work, but I now have these files.

Searching for them doesn't show anything

```
 find . -name "0001"
```

I can see them in Finder and in PHPStorm. But searching for them via PHPStorm shows no results too.

What are they? How can I remove them all quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
find . -name "*0001*"
```